# Why does killing JVM also terminates its child process if waitFor has been used?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

If `waitFor` is not used, killing JVM has no effect on its child process. Here is an example.

Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Sleeping..." > 'log'
sleep 30
echo "Wake up" >> 'log'
```

Java code:

```
public class Code {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./child.sh");
    // process.waitFor();
  }
}
```

After `Java Code` is issued, JVM terminates immediately. And `ps -ef | grep 'child.sh' | grep -v grep` shows:

```
jing      3535  2761  0 13:47 pts/15   00:00:00 bash ./child.sh
```

Then after 30 seconds, I check the content of `log` file in the current directory. The content is:

```
Sleeping...
Wake up
```

And the above `grep` command shows nothing now. Now I uncomment `process.waitFor()` and recompile `Code.java`. After I run `java Code`, I use the above `grep` command to verify that `child.sh` child process is running. Then I issue `Ctrl-C`, JVM terminates. Now running the above `grep` command shows nothing. And the content of `log` file stays as:

```
Sleeping...
```

I have checked `Process`'s Javadoc which does not explain this behavior. Then I use the following code to check the behavior of `fork` , `execlp` and  `waitpid` system calls. And it shows the same behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static void err_sys(const char* msg) {
  printf("%s\n", msg);
  exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
    pid_t   pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        if (execlp("/home/jing/code/lintcode/child.sh", "child.sh", (char *)0) < 0)
            err_sys("execlp error");
    }

  if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0)
    err_sys("wait error");

  exit(0);
}
```

I am using Oracle JDK 1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04. `uname -a` produces:

```
Linux jinglin 3.13.0-108-generic #155-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 11 16:58:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone give an explanation about this effect of `waitFor` and `waitpid`?

[Does Process.waitFor() make the process reliant on the java parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29796031/431698) asks a similar problem on MAC platform. But it lacks details. So I ask this question for my environment here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about `waitPid()`, other than the fact that you keep the parent process in the foreground.

---

If you fork and then wait for the child to finish, you have a (simplified) process tree like this:

```
─┬= 1 init
 └─┬= 2 bash --login
   └─┬= 3 java code
     └─── 4 bash child.sh
```

`java` is the foreground process in the terminal and the child is in its process group.

When you hit ^C the **entire foreground process group gets terminated**.<sup>1</sup>

---

If you *don't* wait, then at first your process tree is the same as the one above.  The `java` process terminates and the child process becomes a child of the process at the root of the process tree.

```
─┬= 1 init
 ├──= 2 bash --login
 └─── 4 bash child.sh
```

The child process finishes executing and terminates normally.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The process group receives a SIGINT, for which the default action is to terminate. However, a different signal handler may be installed.</sup>

Comment: Are you sure? The controlling terminal is the same for all three processes involved, and it never closes.

Comment: True. But how are they terminated then?

Comment: The kernel sends SIGINT to the foreground process group of the session in the terminal.